# The fragments in the viewpager tablayout keep reinstanting every time I reselect the tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have three tabs and when the user goes to the third tab and then back to the first tab - the things in the first tab are not reset and the form keeps reloading.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scorespagemain);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    CAdapter cAdapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), ScoresPageMain.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(cAdapter);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabsstuff);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
    });
}
```

}

`CAdapter` class:

```
public class CAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    String names[] = new String[] {"Top Teams", "Top Scores", "Top Players"};
    Context context;

    public CAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context){
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new TopTeams();
            case 1:
                return new TopScores();
            case 2:
                return new TopPlayers();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return names[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use  - `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int pages);` where the parameter int refers to howmany pages you want to keep in memory

Comment: No need to do anything in the tabUnSelected() and tabReSelected().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `setOffscreenPageLimit()` in your code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Where do I put that? Like in what class or method?

Comment: After `viewPager.setAdapter(cAdapter);`. use `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`

Comment: In your activity class where you are initialize the tab adapter.

Comment: Wow, it works - thank you. Could please explain what that line `setOffscreenPageLimit()` does?

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci Read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci You should accept the answer as you clearly said this works for you.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Ok, please don't tell me what to do! I was going to accept it, and I have accepted as of now. I am sorry, but I was away from my PC for like 5 minutes, so I was not able to accept it on time. I am sorry if I did not accept on time - but it is accept now...

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci This is not even my answer. I see many question with right answers (acknowledged by OP) but not accepted. I am not getting anything out of it for your kind information.

Comment: Thank you @LukazsPioetrszci for accepting this answer. Happy Coding.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 thanks for editing my answer, Keep it up :)

Comment: No problem guys, look @Rohit5k2, I wasn't trying to be rude or anything - it was just the way you told me to accept the answer. I have accepted it nevertheless, and my bad